# Scrapy rules not working when process_request and callback parameter are set

Tags: callback, scrapy, web-crawler, rules

I have this rule for scrapy `CrawlSpider`

```
rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
                    allow= '/topic/\d+/organize$', 
                    restrict_xpaths = '//div[@id= "zh-topic-organize-child-editor"]'
                    ),
           process_request='request_tagPage', callback = "parse_tagPage", follow = True)
    ]
```

`request_tagePage()` refers to a function to add cookie into requests and `parse_tagPage()` refers to a function to parse target pages. According to [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=rule#scrapy.spiders.Rule), CrawlSpider should use `request_tagPage` to make requests and once responses are returned, it calls `parse_tagPage()` to parse it. However, I realized that when `request_tagPage()` is used, spider doesn't call the `parse_tagPage()` at all. So in the actual code, I manually add `parse_tagPage()` callback function as a callback in `request_tagPage`, like this:

```
def request_tagPage(self, request):
    return Request(request.url, meta = {"cookiejar": 1}, \ # attach cookie to the request otherwise I can't login
            headers = self.headers,\
            callback=self.parse_tagPage) # manually add a callback function.
```

It worked but now the spider doesn't use rules to expand its crawling. It closes after crawl the links from `start_urls`. However, before I manually set the `parse_tagPage()` as callback into `request_tagPage()`, the rules works. So I am thinking this maybe a bug? Is a way to enable `request_tagPage()`, which I need to attach cookie in the request, `parse_tagPage()` , which used to parse a page and `rules`, which directs spider to crawl?

Comment: Are you sure your linkextactor is even working? open up a website via `scrapy shell url` and import LinkExtractor and try using it with the same arguments on the `response.body`.

Comment: It's working. When parse_tagPage() isn't used as callback function in the request_tagPage(), I see from console that spider crawls as it should be. From scrapy's [documentation on Rule object](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=rule#scrapy.spiders.Rule), I thought set parse_tagPage() as callback for the Rule is enough, it turned out callback function wasn't called at all. So I have to put callback in the request_tagPage(). Then the callbback is called but spider loses ability to follow links, except those in the start_urls.

Comment: Have you tried to not construct brand-new `Request` object, but use `Request.replace()` method instead? Eg. `return request.replace(meta={'cookiejar': 1}, headers=self.headers)`. `CrawlSpider` handles all pages in its own `parse()` callback that processes crawl rules, so changing `callback` muanually doesn't seem like a good way to go.

Comment: @shirk3y tried with request.replace(). It worked the same however. Thanks the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. `CrawlSpider` uses its default `parse()` to apply the rules. So when my custom `parse_tagPage()` is called, there is no more `parse()` follows up to keep applying the rules. Solution is to simply add the default `parse()` into my custom `parse_tagPage()`. It now looks like this:

```
def parse_tagPage(self, response):
    # parse the response, get the information I want...
    # save the information into a local file...
    return self.parse(response) # simply calls the default parse() function to enable the rules
```

Answer (score 5):

Requests generated by `CrawlSpider` rules use [internal callbacks and use `meta` to do their "magic"](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py#L62).

I suggest that you don't recreate Requests from scratch in your rules' `process_request` hooks (or you'll probably end-up reimplementing what `CrawlSpider` does for you already).

Instead, if you just want to add cookies and special headers, you can use [`.replace()` method on the request](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.replace) that is passed to `request_tagPage`, so that the "magic" of `CrawlSpider` is preserved.

Something like this should be enough:

```
def request_tagPage(self, request):
    tagged = request.replace(headers=self.headers)
    tagged.meta.update(cookiejar=1)
    return tagged
```