# Scrapy using start_requests with rules

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I can't find any solution for using start_requests with rules, also I haven't seen any example on the Internet with this two. My purpose is simple, I wanna redefine start_request function to get an ability catch all exceptions dunring requests and also use meta in requests. This is a code of my spider:

class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['www.oreilly.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/practical-postgresql/9781449309770/ch04s05.html']

```
# Base on scrapy doc
def start_requests(self):
    for u in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(u, callback=self.parse_item, errback=self.errback_httpbin, dont_filter=True)

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = {}
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//head/title/text()').extract()
    item['url'] = response.url
    yield item

def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
    self.logger.error('ERRRRROR - {}'.format(failure))
```

This code scrape only one page. I try to modify it and instead of:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = {}
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//head/title/text()').extract()
    item['url'] = response.url
    yield item
```

I've tried to use this, based on this answer

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = {}
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//head/title/text()').extract()
    item['url'] = response.url
    return self.parse(response)
```

It seems to work, but it doesn't scrape anything, even if I add parse function to my spider. Does anybody know how to use start_request and rules together? I will be glad any information about this topic. Have a nice coding!

Comment: somebody, any ideas?

Comment: I asked a similar question last week, but couldn't find a way either. This was the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616527/scrapy-linkextractor-in-control-flow-and-why-it-doesnt-work

Comment: @gunesevitan, have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280133/scrapy-rules-not-working-when-process-request-and-callback-parameter-are-set)? This stuff get my Rules work but it doesn't crawl enething because parse func is empty. If I redefine parse func it still doesn't work(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866873/scrapy-get-website-with-error-dns-lookup-failed) for handle errback in LinkExtractor

Thanks this dude!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, but frankly speaking I don't know how it works but it sertantly does it.

```
class TSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 't'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrapes.com']
    start_urls = ['https://books.toscrapes.com']
    login_page = 'https://books.toscrapes.com'

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login, errback=self.errback_httpbin, dont_filter=True)

    def login(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = {}
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//head/title/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = response.url
        yield item

    def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
        self.logger.error('ERRRRROR - {}'.format(failure))
```

Comment: this code works only if a page has form therefore it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

To catch errors from your `rules` you need to define `errback` for your `Rule()`. But unfortunately this is not possible now.

You need to parse and `yield` `request` by yourself (this way you can use `errback`) or process each `response` using `middleware`.

Comment: maybe I wrote not so clear, bur rules in code above don't work.