# Scrapy spider crawls the main page but not scrape next pages of same category

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Need some help here. My code is working when I am crawling one category page via (scrapy.Spider). However when I try to scrape the next page of same category, it does not seems to goto next page and don't scrape at all.

**Here is code**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import item
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse,Response
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.selector.unified import _response_from_text
from ..items import ScrapybooksspiderItem
class ScrapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapp'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        categ=response.xpath('//div[@class="side_categories"]/ul[@class="nav nav-list"]/li/ul/li')
        # for category in  categ:
        Category_Name=categ.xpath('.//a[contains(text(),"Historical Fiction")]/text()').get().replace('\n',"").strip()
        Kategorylink=categ.xpath('.//a[contains(text(),"Historical Fiction")]/@href').get().replace('\n',"").strip()
        yield response.follow(Kategorylink,callback=self.info_parse,cb_kwargs={'category_name':Category_Name,'Category_link':Kategorylink})
    
    def info_parse(self,response,category_name,Category_link):
        
        bookurl=response.xpath('//section/div/ol/li/article[@class="product_pod"]/h3/a/@href')
        
        for books in bookurl:
            BOOK=books.get()
            Boooks_info_url=response.urljoin(BOOK)        
            respons = Boooks_info_url            
            ponse = HtmlResponse(url=respons, body=requests.get(respons).text, encoding='utf-8') 
            bookprize=ponse.xpath('//*/p[@class="price_color"]/text()').get()                  
            yield {
                'Category_Name':category_name,                
                'Category_link':Category_link,
                'Bookurl':Boooks_info_url,
                'Bookprize':bookprize
            }

        next_page=response.xpath('//*[@class="next"]/a[contains(text(),"next")]/@href').get()
        if next_page:        
         word=Category_link          
         listst=word.split('/')
         length=len(listst)
         final_length=length-1
         lam=listst[-1]
         dellast=listst.pop()
         listst.insert(final_length,next_page)
         del listst[:-1]
         newst="/".join(listst)
         final_url=newst  
         print('\n',final_url,'\n')          
         yield response.follow(url=final_url,callback=self.info_parse)
```

**here is command prompt output**

```
{'Category_Name': 'Historical Fiction', 'Category_link': 'catalogue/category/books/historical-fiction_4/index.html', 'Bookurl': 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/the-guernsey-literary-and-potato-peel-pie-society_253/index.html', 'Bookprize': 'Â£49.53'}
2021-09-29 04:30:25 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): books.toscrape.com:80
2021-09-29 04:30:26 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://books.toscrape.com:80 "GET /catalogue/girl-in-the-blue-coat_160/index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2021-09-29 04:30:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/historical-fiction_4/index.html>
{'Category_Name': 'Historical Fiction', 'Category_link': 'catalogue/category/books/historical-fiction_4/index.html', 'Bookurl': 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/girl-in-the-blue-coat_160/index.html', 'Bookprize': 'Â£46.83'}

 page-2.html

2021-09-29 04:30:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/historical-fiction_4/page-2.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/historical-fiction_4/index.html)
2021-09-29 04:30:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/historical-fiction_4/page-2.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/historical-fiction_4/index.html)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abu Bakar Siddique\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 858, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
TypeError: info_parse() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'category_name' and 'Category_link'
2021-09-29 04:30:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Thanking in advance for awesome support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the error you're getting. It's because your info_parse function expect arguments that you don't send.

```
   def info_parse(self,response,category_name,Category_link):

        bookurl=response.xpath('//section/div/ol/li/article[@class="product_pod"]/h3/a/@href')

        for books in bookurl:
            BOOK=books.get()
            Boooks_info_url=response.urljoin(BOOK)
            respons = Boooks_info_url
            ponse = HtmlResponse(url=respons, body=requests.get(respons).text, encoding='utf-8')
            bookprize=ponse.xpath('//*/p[@class="price_color"]/text()').get()
            yield {
                'Category_Name':category_name,
                'Category_link':Category_link,
                'Bookurl':Boooks_info_url,
                'Bookprize':bookprize
            }

        next_page=response.xpath('//*[@class="next"]/a[contains(text(),"next")]/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            word=Category_link
            listst=word.split('/')
            length=len(listst)
            final_length=length-1
            lam=listst[-1]
            dellast=listst.pop()
            listst.insert(final_length,next_page)
            del listst[:-1]
            newst="/".join(listst)
            final_url=newst
            print('\n',final_url,'\n')
            yield response.follow(url=final_url,callback=self.info_parse,cb_kwargs={'category_name':category_name,'Category_link':Category_link})
```

It should work.

***EDIT:*** (your code with a few changes)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import item
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse,Response
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.selector.unified import _response_from_text
from ..items import ScrapybooksspiderItem


class ScrapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapp'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        categ=response.xpath('//div[@class="side_categories"]/ul[@class="nav nav-list"]/li/ul/li')
        for category in categ:
            Category_Name=category.xpath('./a/text()').get().strip()
            Kategorylink=category.xpath('./a/@href').get()
            yield response.follow(Kategorylink,callback=self.info_parse,cb_kwargs={'category_name':Category_Name,'Category_link':Kategorylink})

    def info_parse(self,response,category_name,Category_link):
        bookurl=response.xpath('//section/div/ol/li/article[@class="product_pod"]/h3/a/@href')

        for books in bookurl:
            BOOK=books.get()
            Boooks_info_url=response.urljoin(BOOK)
            bookprize=response.xpath('//*/p[@class="price_color"]/text()').get()
            yield {
                'Category_Name':category_name,
                'Category_link':Category_link,
                'Bookurl':Boooks_info_url,
                'Bookprize':bookprize
            }

        next_page=response.xpath('//*[@class="next"]/a[contains(text(),"next")]/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            word=Category_link
            listst=word.split('/')
            length=len(listst)
            final_length=length-1
            lam=listst[-1]
            dellast=listst.pop()
            listst.insert(final_length,next_page)
            del listst[:-1]
            newst="/".join(listst)
            final_url=newst
            print('\n',final_url,'\n')
            yield response.follow(url=final_url,callback=self.info_parse,cb_kwargs={'category_name':category_name,'Category_link':Category_link})
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for responding. I have already applied this option. But unfortunately. It won't work. Even if I did this, spider don't scrap next page. Can you help me regarding that please?

Comment: @AbuBakarSiddique, See edit, also why do you use requests and BeautifulSoup libraries with scrapy?

Comment: Mann, You are rocking.. my code works now. Thank you very much. I am using requests and beautiful soup because I was thinking response won't fetch html content of product pages. That's why do so. Your skills are appreciated. Please give me few tips to be proficents in scraping and how to scrap recaptcha sites. Appreciated

Comment: @AbuBakarSiddique no problem. Please remember to accept the answer. Learn from doing projects (for example try to write this project with CrawlSpider), and from the scrapy documentation. About recaptcha I'm in the same boat with you.

Comment: Hey Superuser, I have a query that can we use start_request and rule in the same spyder? If so, can you provide me a template. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean CrawlSpider rules?

Comment: Yes, Crawl spider

Comment: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723495/scrapy-using-start-requests-with-rules)